# Pass a Java class reference as a function parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to pass a reference to a class to a function:

```
getCallData(ServiceCallBase::class.java)

fun getCallData(msg: Message, t: KClass<Any>): String {
   return gson.fromJson((msg.obj as Bundle).getString(SERVICE_BUNDLE_KEY_DATA_TO_SERVICE), t)
}
```

The t parameter is not correct here. How do I correctly define the t parameter? The closest I can get is:

```
private inline fun <reified T> getCallData(msg: Message): String {
    return gson.fromJson((msg.obj as Bundle).getString(SERVICE_BUNDLE_KEY_DATA_TO_SERVICE), T)
}
```

But here T is not an expression.

Comment: Wouldn't `t: Class<*>` work?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
inline fun <reified T> getCallData(msg: Message): String {
        return gson.fromJson((msg.obj as Bundle)
                .getString(SERVICE_BUNDLE_KEY_DATA_TO_SERVICE), T::class.java)
    }
```

and use it like this :

```
getCallData<ServiceCallBase>(Message())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ServiceCallBase` is not a subtype of `Any`. You should change the signature to:

```
fun getCallData(t: KClass<*>) { ... }
```

Then, to call this function just use:

```
getCallData(ServiceCallBase::class)
```

But, to do that in more kotlin way use the second snipped you pasted:

```
inline fun <reified T> getCallData() { /* use T::class property here */ }
```

and call the function like this:

```
getCallData<ServiceCallBase>()
```